# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Input_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, q-learning, dqn

I am trying to create a Flappy Bird AI with Convolutional Layers and Dense Layers, but at the "Train" step (Function fit()) I get the following error message:

```
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

Training for 500000 steps ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-e21cf8798454> in <module>()
----> 1 dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, visualize=False, verbose=2) #fit = training, training for 5 Mio, timesteps eig bei 5000000
      2 #value's which are important: episode reward, mean reward

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils_v1.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    634                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    635                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 636                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    637         if not check_batch_axis:
    638           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Input_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)
```

I have found an example on the internet where only Dense Layers were used (Copyright (c) 2020 Gabriel Nogueira (Talendar)). I would like to build a network with Conv2D and Dense Layers, but something doesn't seem to fit.

The code is built as follows:

```
import sys
import os

import flappy_bird_gym 
env = flappy_bird_gym.make("FlappyBird-v0") #greyscale format 

env.action_space #Discrete(2)
env.observation_space #Box(-inf, inf, (2,), float32)

actions = env.action_space.n #2
obs = env.observation_space.shape[0] #2

#Network:
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Input

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf

#build model
def build_model(obs, actions):

  model = Sequential() 

  model.add(Conv2D(32, (8,8), name='Input', padding='same',input_shape=(1,obs,1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same', name='maxpooling1'))

  model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv1'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same', name='maxpooling2'))
 
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv2'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same', name='maxpooling3'))
  
  model.add(Flatten())
  
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', name='Dense1')) 
  model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear',name='Output'))
  
  return model

model = build_model(obs, actions)
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 Input (Conv2D)              (None, 1, 2, 32)          2080      
                                                                 
 maxpooling1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 32)          0         
                                                                 
 Conv1 (Conv2D)              (None, 1, 1, 64)          32832     
                                                                 
 maxpooling2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 Conv2 (Conv2D)              (None, 1, 1, 64)          36928     
                                                                 
 maxpooling3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 flatten_20 (Flatten)        (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 Dense1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               16640     
                                                                 
 Output (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 88,994
Trainable params: 88,994
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

#RL
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy

#build agent:
def build_agent(): 
  policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=0.5, value_min=.0001, value_test=.0, nb_steps=6000000)
  memory = SequentialMemory(limit=100000, window_length=1)
  dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, #RL Algorithm
                enable_dueling_network=True, dueling_type='avg', #technique you use 
                nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=5000)
  return dqn
  
dqn = build_agent() 

#train:
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=0.00025)) 

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=500000, visualize=False, verbose=2) #here the error occurs
```

--> in the last line the error occurs

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your input data.

As you can see the first layer is expecting the data to have dimension `(None, 1, 2, 32)` (The None is just the number of samples in the array). The key thing is your data has shape `(1,2,2)` and not `(1, 2, 32)`. If you show us your data or maybe the what kind of data we can probably help a bit more on how to reshape it properly in order for the error to disappear.

Comment: I have used a network of dense layers as a basis. When I run this code, everything works. There the input_shape is specified as follows: input_shape=(1, obs). Do you know how I can change this input to a suitable input_shape for a Conv2D Layer?

Comment: What is the current shape of your data? Is it just (1, 2, 2)? That would mean you have one sample of data with a shape of (2,2) which is strange